# How to cut at vertex position of another object?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

[image]

I want to cut the top face of the cube exactly along the bottom edge of the plane. What would be the best way to do that? When I use the knife tool on the cube, it doesn't snap to the vertices of the plane, so it never ends up being precise.

In this example I have both meshes in one object, but it would be even more useful to just cut one object based on another objects vertices/edges without having to combine them.

Is there something like 'cut edge at cursor'? That way I could set the cursor to the vertex first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the plane and cube belong to the same mesh, in Edit mode, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> Face Menu > *Intersect (Knife)*. It has 3 modes:

[image]

(Illustrations exploded to show separate parts)

- **All**: all the results of intersection are split to separate islands
- **Cut**: Edges are created, but not split, at intersections in all parts
- **Merge**: Edges are created at intersections, all vertices merged, resulting here in an internal face.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, I did not know about that tool. In my example I was trying to do it with 2 separate objects, but I can just duplicate the face in question, join it with the cube and use your technique.