# The intersection part of a plane

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

I have a cube sliced by a plane:

[image]

I would like to get the part of the plane inside the cube. So I figured a boolean modifier would the trick. Whether I apply it to the cube or plane or chose union, intersect or difference I always end up with some 3D object - some part of the cube. I would like to have only the plane part of the boolean.

Comment: Not spot-on, but maybe [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211694/35559) helps?

Comment: Yeah it close. I did look at the knife tool too. But this solution seem to require the both object belong to the same mesh. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I took a cube, gave it the _Boolean_ modifier set to _Intersect_ and selected the plane as the other object. The result is the part of the plane that's inside the cube. Of course you have to make the original plane invisible, otherwise it will obstruct the view on the resulting boolean object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following @Gordon Brinkmann's comment, in Blender 2.9x, using the 'Fast' *Boolean* option, (the modifier assigned to the plane,) it seems to work OK, here:

[image]

...across the angles.

[image]

But 'Exact' seems to fail; it includes the volume in the cube behind the plane's normal.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I wanted... Seems like a bug.

Comment: nice animation by the way ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's my setup only that I assigned the modifier to the cube - but on intersect it doesn't matter which object. Should not only work with _Fast_ but _Exact_, too. I didn't give it as an answer because that's just the normal way to use the _Boolean_ modifier...