# Any way to make a curve from intersection of two objectives?

Tags: bezier-curves, project

Maybe its a noob question but I still cant find a simple solution about how to get a curve (or mesh edges) from intersection of two objectives.
Something like project knife doing, but there should be a simplier solution.

[image]

Comment: [Knife Intersect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211694/35559)?

Answer (score 1):

You could duplicate one of the objects, use boolean modifier with the other object and apply it. You would get geometry that contains the edge, so only problem left is to select it. You could use ctrl+clicking to select shortest path and this way select all the edges you need, then invert selection with ctrl+i and delete everything else. Once you are left with a mesh object that contains only edges of the intersection edge, you can convert it to curve (Object menu-> Convert To-> Curve)

Comment: Its strange that it there no simpler solution. Like making slices in DecalMachine.

Comment: @Vadim "Knife" mode is considered to be added by the boolean dev Howard Trickey https://devtalk.blender.org/t/boolean-improvements/6200/206

Comment: I am definitely not claiming it's the only or the best way - I have no idea. Its just a way that came to my mind without thinking too much to be honest. There may be a simpler solution as well.

Comment: I guess it's so easy with DecalMachine because it's an addon which is build to do all the complex things for you in the background... if I build a very complex material consisting of a lot of nodes, you could say this is not an easy way. But if I put them all in one group node with a simple input and output this also makes it much easier for you to use - it just doesn't change the fact that someone has to build that complex setup.

Comment: But it is an easy task. In fact if you take two objectives, intersect them and switch shading mode to wireframe mode -> you will see a curve right in a place where this objectives are intersecting. So the engine already rendering that curve. The task is only to get it out.